# How is it possible to edit data inside Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer

Tags: c#, uwp, vpn

in UWP, VPN plugins should encapsulate IP Packets received from the OS by editing the given Buffer(Storage.Streams.Buffer), the buffer is read-only so i can't replace it with another buffer.
in c++/winrt there is a function named data() inside Buffer which returns uint8 pointer, but there's not such field or function in c#.
how am i supposed to edit data in Buffer?

```
        public void Encapsulate(VpnChannel channel, VpnPacketBufferList packets, VpnPacketBufferList encapulatedPackets)
        {
            var packet = packets.RemoveAtBegin();
            var dataBuffer = packet.Buffer; //read-only field
            /*How to edit above buffer without replacing it*/


        }
```

Comment: Why do want to edit `IBuffer`? And have you tried to copy a new buffer and edit the copy ?

Comment: the buffer field in the VpnPacketBuffer is read only and has no set function, so it should be edited, the documentation tells the same

Answer (score 1):

found it out, there's a function belonging to Array class and in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace named `CopyTo(IBuffer)`
and doesn't even seem to be in the Microsoft documentations.

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic;
.
.
.
byte [] data;
data.CopyTo(YourBuffer);
```